# GameCenter won't login on iPad (it does on iPhone)

Tags: ios, ipad, game-center

I added the login code for GameKit/Gamecenter and it does work fine on iPhone/iPod. Unfortunately on my iPad (since I disabled Gamecenter for my App) it doesn ot work anymore.

The issue is that I now want to test it and I have deleted the App from my iPad, re-installed it, re-logged on GameCenter and it still won't ask me for GameCenter login.

If I do the same on iPod/iPhone (disable app, reinstall and relogin) it will ask me to connect to GameCenter.

Is there some step I am missing? Why does it not work on iPad?

I am using a real iPad with iOS 7.01.
It used to work fine. When I run the same App on the iPad simulator it does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> Settings / General / Reset / Reset All Settings.

I don't think they provide any other way of doing it - that works with GameCenter.

On iOS just login out and in to GameCenter was solving a problem - on iOS 7 it doesn't work anymore. I was not able to find any changelog for that on Apple site, but on 2 of my devices I had to reset settings as well to reenable one of my games.